# Phonegap Navigation bar not working for multiple html pages

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova

I am working on multiple HTML page phoneGap application and i want to implement a navigation bar.

I am using the following code for phoneGap [navigation bar](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/NavigationBar) implementation:

In `index.html`, I have defined navigation bar like this:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  plugins.navigationBar.init();

  // or .create("BlackOpaque") to apply a certain style
  plugins.navigationBar.create("BlackOpaque"); 

  plugins.navigationBar.setTitle("Home");
  plugins.navigationBar.hideLeftButton();
  plugins.navigationBar.hideRightButton();
  plugins.navigationBar.show();
}
```

When i run app, it creates a nav bar at top of index page with title labelled as `HOME`, without left or right `navBarButton` as I don't need it in home page.

But when I go to next HTML page `xyz.html` by clicking on a button, the `navBar` show same behaviour: **i.e** same Title without left and write button.

But I want it to change the title for the currently loaded page and also insert `leftNavBarButton` label as back so that I can also go back to previous page.

But it is not happening. I have also tried to write a script in `xyz.html` page that should change its title and put `leftNavBarButton` as back but not working.

Its static throughout the app with same title and i am unable to go back to previous page. I want its behaviour to be global which changes with every page and maintain the state of previous pages as well! How can i do this?

Comment: and do i need to include navigationbar.js in every html page?

Comment: I do have almost the same problem. When I am in index.html. My NavigationBar is woriking with a title and left button. If I go to another html-file. Like test.html. I do see my navigationBar with the title and a left button, but the link is not working. What do I have to do that in sub-htmls the buttons on the navigationBar are still working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a single-page template (= 1 jQuery Mobile page per HTML file), you have to include your JS code in every HTML files.

What you can do is to put all your custom JS code inside a JS file and import it in every HTML pages you have. Also, import any other JS lib you'll use in every pages.

**Ex:**

```
<script src="./js/navigationbar.js"</script>
<script src="./js/myjs.js"></script>
...
...
```

Another solution would be to force the refresh of the pages when navigating to them.

In this case, you don't have to import all your JS code in every pages, and for each HTML file, you can import the JS files which are required for this given file.